# SQL Server Continues to Swap RAM After Using a Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, memory-management, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a dev computer running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise and SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, with 8GB of RAM.  As I write code and use the database, SQL Server will use more-and-more RAM (*which is fine!*).

If I run `Hyper-V Manager` and start a virtual machine, then SQL Server will release **all** the RAM it can.  It runs in this **minimal memory mode** mode even after all Virtual Machines are shut down.  The only way to get SQL Server to run normally again is to restart the MSSQLServer service, or reboot the computer -- both of which are sometimes very inconvenient.

Does anyone know of another way to get SQL Server 2008 R2 to use RAM normally again (**not** in **minimal memory mode**), without restarting SQL Server or rebooting?